# Spring Boot Keyloak Get a bearer token for currently logged in user

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

Am currently developing an application using Keycloak for authorization/authentication, which logs in a user then redirects them to a Spring Boot application at the back. I now want to create a new request from the current Spring Boot application to a 3rd party service which is tied to the same Keycloak instance.

I want to acquire the existing bearer token for the currently logged in user, so I can set it in the Authorization header for the next request to the 3rd Party. I cannot use a fresh token as the keys used to sign and verify the token are from the Keycloak instance and already configured on the 3rd party service. Is there a way to get a bearer token from Keycloak from the currently logged in user without prompting the user for a password again?

Comment: You could extract the Bearer Token in your Spring Boot application from the request and use this token for the request to your third party service.

Comment: @DanielWosch I tried that using interceptors, its not present at all. Seems when Keycloak redirects to app, the Authorization header is removed and replaced with a session token/cookie.

Comment: Okay, 'strange'. How does the redirect happen? I mean from authentication to your spring boot application.

Comment: @DanielWosch I have integrated Keycloak into my Spring Boot app. When user opens application, Keycloak captures the request and validates. If not authorized, keycloak redirects to separate Keycloak server to authenticate and authorize. That server then sets other params/values/cookies EXCEPT the original Bearer token in the request, and redirects back to application. Then for every request afterwards, keycloak always intercepts and validates the tokens sent

Comment: So issue comes when I want to use the same auth parameters on another service utilizing same Keycloak instance for authentication from the current service. I need to pass in the original Bearer token, but can't find a way to regenerate/fetch it from current service without prompting the user. I can't ask for a password as am going to be using that service call several times, thus will be a bad experience to the user if I keep asking for a password. Unless there's another way to authenticate using existing cookies/headers on third party service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by utilizing Keycloak's option to upload my own keys for signature or token generation and verification. I created another separate RSA key-pair, uploaded the private key onto Keycloak as the active key, and also saved it separately where each service can access it. Then whenever the UI service needs to authenticate to another service, I create a new token with details from the current token and sign it with the private key, then the other service can easily verify the token without touching it as Keycloak has the copies of both the private and public keys.